# Fastest Method To Read Thousands of JSON Files in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ipython

I have a number of JSON files I need to analyze. I am using iPython (`Python 3.5.2 | IPython 5.0.0`), reading in the files to a dictionary and appending each dictionary to a list.

My main bottleneck is reading in the files. Some files are smaller, and are read quickly, but the larger files are slowing me down.

Here is some example code (sorry, I cannot provide the actual data files):

```
import json
import glob

def read_json_files(path_to_file):
    with open(path_to_file) as p:
        data = json.load(p)
        p.close()
    return data

def giant_list(json_files):
    data_list = []
    for f in json_files:
        data_list.append(read_json_files(f))
    return data_list

support_files = glob.glob('/Users/path/to/support_tickets_*.json')
small_file_test = giant_list(support_files)

event_files = glob.glob('/Users/path/to/google_analytics_data_*.json')
large_file_test = giant_list(event_files)
```

The support tickets are very small in size--largest I've seen is 6KB. So, this code runs pretty fast:

```
In [3]: len(support_files)
Out[3]: 5278

In [5]: %timeit giant_list(support_files)
1 loop, best of 3: 557 ms per loop
```

But larger files definitely are slowing me down...these event files can reach ~2.5MB each:

```
In [7]: len(event_files) # there will be a lot more of these soon :-/
Out[7]: 397

In [8]: %timeit giant_list(event_files)
1 loop, best of 3: 14.2 s per loop
```

I've researched how to speed up the process and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706101/python-json-decoding-performance), however, when using UltraJSON the timing was just slightly worse:

```
In [3]: %timeit giant_list(traffic_files)
1 loop, best of 3: 16.3 s per loop
```

SimpleJSON did not do much better:

```
In [4]: %timeit giant_list(traffic_files)
1 loop, best of 3: 16.3 s per loop
```

Any tips on how to optimize this code and more efficiently read a lot of JSON files into Python is much appreciated.

Finally, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781716/loading-large-twitter-json-data-7gb-into-python) is the closest I've found to my question, but deals with one giant JSON file, not many smaller sized ones.

Comment: Your bottleneck is I/O, not parsing speed. Not much to be done other than get a faster disk (do you run on an SSD yet?).

Comment: And `json` in the Python library is the exact same project as `simplejson`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How did you reach that conclusion? Based on some quick tests, `json.load()` reaches about 46MiB/s on a fast CPU. That's not out of reach for disk-based storage, nevermind SSDs. And that's ignoring the possibility that his input files are cached in memory...

Comment: @measureallthethings How long is it currently taking to load those json files? Note that you're trying to read _and parse_ about 1.2GiB of data. Also note that those json entitites may end up using much more memory as Python objects. The integer `5` takes one byte in json, but may cost something like 16 bytes as a Python object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use list comprehension to avoid resizing list multiple times.

```
def giant_list(json_files):
    return [read_json_file(path) for path in json_files]
```

You are closing file object twice, simply do it once (on exiting `with` file would be closed automatically)

```
def read_json_file(path_to_file):
    with open(path_to_file) as p:
        return json.load(p)
```

At the end of the day, your problem is I/O bound, but these changes will help a little bit. Also, I have to ask - do you really have to have all these dictionaries in the memory at the same time?

Comment: Good question--the thousands of smaller files I do not need in memory at the same time. In each case, there are ~5 specific fields I am going to extract, then discard the rest of the dictionary. When it comes to larger event files, I have even more problems...it is Google Analytics data and parsing it makes me cry: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#parsing_the_v4_response. Moreover, I parse it then convert to a Pandas DataFrame...probably going to save that for another post :-/

Comment: Even simpler: I ditched the `giant_list()` function and just do a list comprehension directly: `[read_json_file(path) for path in event_files]`

Comment: would the dictionary be a bottle neck here or did you mention it due to its bad form?